# GSON - trim string during deserialization from JSON

Tags: java, json, string, gson

I have a JSON string that is parsed using the GSON library into a Map like so:

```
static Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();
// note the trailing/leading white spaces
String data = "{'employee.name':'Bob  ','employee.country':'  Spain  '}";

Map<String, String> parsedData = gson.fromJson(data, type);
```

The problem I have is, my JSON attribute values have trailing/leading whitespaces that needs to be trimmed. Ideally, I want this to be done when the data is parsed to the Map using GSON. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Why not? ... `for (String key : parsedData.keySet()) parsedData.put(key, parsedData.get(key).trim());`  Admittedly this is done ***after*** the parse - which is different from the request you have posted in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement custom `com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer` deserializer which trims `String` values:

```
class StringTrimJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        final String value = json.getAsString();
        return value == null ? null : value.trim();
    }
}
```

And, you need to register it:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new StringTrimJsonDeserializer())
        .create();
```